# Animate Locomotive by follow Path

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, bezier-curves, path

I want my locomotive to follow rails over a hill.
The loc should always be on the rails.
I've tried a few things (such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OruVKMGGPX8), but I always come back to the same problem: the locomotive follows the rail, but leans into the curve:

[image]

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com is the place to upload .blend files to be shared. Once uploaded, copy the generated link, edit your question here and paste the link in. Well prepared and explained screenshots can also help.

Answer (score 4):

If your curve is flat you can simply change the curve type to 2D to ignore the tilt for each control point:

[image]

If it is 3D and you want to keep it that way, you need to reset the tilt of each control point that isn't set to 0 degrees:

[image]

EDIT: You can also try setting the *Twist Method* to *Z-Up*.

EDIT 2 (after seeing the blend file):

Start with applying all transform on the curve (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *All Transforms*), then set the *Twist Method* on the curve to *Z-Up*. Then you'll have to tweak the Z-rotation of the locomotive to make it line up with the track, something like -28 degrees seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: It's a 3d hill with a 3d curve! And each tilt of all control points are set to 0 degrees!

Comment: Ok, upload the blend file so we can take a look.

Comment: Ok, the file is uploaded on Blend exchange! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=nExr8DvQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/nExr8DvQ/)

Comment: @Capodelosplasticos, see my updated answer.

Comment: Hey Tobias, thank you for your help!!! I will try it out next weekend!!

Comment: That's really cool, it works perfectly!!!

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

if you delete your path constraint and if you use a bone and use follow path constraint like this:

[image]

and apply scale + rotation for curve + locomotive and use edit mode to place the locomotive exact on the rails, you will get this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I investigated WHY it works, because to my understanding it shouldn't… So apparently the real solution is to **apply the rotation of the curve** and - which you don't mention, but you did it - **set twist method to z-up**. The twist didn't work for me when I tried it, because I was unaware of curve's rotation. And this is what Tobias Einarsson said in the first answer in the thread 

Comment: uhm...just read...i wrote "apply scale + rotation for curve + locomotive"

Comment: Notice the - hyphen inset - is after the "and" in my prior comment :P

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for your help!!! I will try it out next weekend!!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything on automatically aligning curve tilt to +Z, so you would need to use a [complex geonodes setup](https://blenderartists.org/t/z-up-curve-tilt-nodegroup-for-blender-3-0-geometry-nodes/1351897), then, because apparently the constraint isn't affected by geonodes, you would need to capture the calculated tilt as attribute, make Python read the evaluated attribute and write it to the original geometry (and you would need to run the Python script after each modification of the curve)…

**Or** you could just align your object up using Geometry Nodes:

1. Clear all rotations on your loco.
2. Change Forward Axis of your tracking to $-x$, because that's the direction your loco looks at when you duplicate it and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> clear parent: [image]
3. Add Geonodes setup to your loco:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Of course you could animate it all in geonodes to begin with:

[image]

Comment: Hey Markus, thank you for your help!!! I will try it out next weekend!!

Comment: @Capodelosplasticos consider my answer if you want to learn something new, but I think Tobias' answer is on point and most appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: You've right, Tobias solution is very smart and also easy! But you have to find out first! Thanks anyway for your help